# Check for null using generic delegate parameters with param keyword

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates, func

I have a interesting case here . I have a method call as

```
bool pass= Check.CheckNotNull<RemoveRoleFromUserCommand>(x => x.RoleName, x => x.UserId);
```

Now I want to Make this method definition as something like this ..

```
public static void CheckNotNull<T>(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] @params)
    {
        return @params.All(x=> ..... );
    }
```

How to check for all of the values in `@params` delegate for all values that I have passed.

Comment: Why `Expression<Func<T, object>>` and not `Func<T, object>`?

Comment: @Enigmativity yes , I agree , Func<> is the right way to do it since I m not traversing the tree elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you want to invoke the delegates, you need an instance of `T`. So add that as an argument.

```
public static bool CheckNotNull<T>(T item, params Func<T, object>[] @params)
{
    return @params.All(selector => selector(item) != null );
}
```

---

In response to the comment:

```
public static bool CheckNotNull<T>(T item, params Func<T, object>[] @params)
{
    return @params.All(selector =>
        {
            var selected = selector(item);
            return selected is string? string.IsNullOrEmpty(selected as string) : selected != null;
        } );
}
```

Comment: What if I need to check that same if the object is of type string ? I know this would work out . Just in case if the object is a string and I want it to be checked for both string / object types ? i.e i m talking about `String.isNullorempty()`

Comment: @Joy you can check if `selector(item) is string` and do custom verification logic

Comment: @Joy That's a whole different question, but i've updated my answer anyway.